# reract leaflet Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid expected a string or a class/functionbut got: undefined

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to install the first example from react-leaflet and i get this warning

Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

it's working but i can't get rid of the warning, i tried all the default and none default versions but still struggling, does anyone had the same problem?

thx franz

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

export function MapComponent() {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[51.505, -0.09]}
      zoom={13}
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
      id="map"
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```